# Detect Eye using HSV value in Open CV

Tags: c, opencv, eye-detection

I want to detect an Eye, I have some code where I can detect blue color object, so if I made changes(how I can?) then it would be possible for me to detect an eye. As the below color has its own specific  range value so, if I specify the eye color HSV value then can I detect EYE with this method.

In this below code I am going to detect BLUE Color Object, please tell me that where I do changes in my code so that I could get EYE using Open CV.

```
     IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* img)
    {
    // Convert the image into an HSV image
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

    IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
      //For detecting BLUE color i have this HSV value, 
     cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(112, 100, 100), cvScalar(124, 255, 255), imgThreshed);//this will not recognize the yellow color
     cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
      return imgThreshed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eye detection is much easier with Haar classifier.
[link here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

Answer (score 1):

Such a simple method may work at extracting a blue object using some thresholding but even if it could be adapted using a different colour black? blue? green? Everyone has different eye colours. I don't see a non hacky method working for you using blob extraction like this based on a HSV threshold value. This method works well on large blocks of the same colour, i.e. removing a blue background.

Look more at shape, everyone has different coloured eyes but the shape is circular/ellipse ish. There are varients of the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) for detecting circles.

> ...the Hough transform has been extended to identifying positions of
>   arbitrary shapes, most commonly circles or ellipses.